# What is the proper way to check if id exists or not ? (ejs, mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

If i have code like:

**index.js**

```
app.get('/link/:id', (req, res) => {
 collection.find({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, collection) => {
 if(err) res.send(err)
 else {
   res.render('link', { collection: collection });
 }
```

**link.ejs**

```
<% if(collection != 'undefined') { %>
   <li><%= collection.userName %></li>
   <li><%= collection.address %></li>
<% }else{ %>
   <p>Data not found</p>
<% } %>
```

But it also shows this error:

**error:**

```
Cannot read property 'userName' of undefined
```

so what is the solution?

Comment: you can replace `if (collection != 'undefined')` with just `if (collection)` and it will return false if it's undefined. You're just comparing collection with the string `undefined`

Comment: check this out for more info on undefined: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined